# Spring RequestScoped bean declared inside ApplicationScoped bean is thread safe?

Tags: spring-mvc

Spring application scoped bean contains Request scoped bean. What will happen when multiple requests concurrently access request scoped bean inside the application scoped bean?

Comment: Each thread will use the bean associated with the request currently handled by that thread. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection

Comment: what do you mean by  **application scoped bean**?

Comment: @secretsuperstar https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-application